# I need help with wp_lostpassword, wp_register and wp_login_form

Tags: password

[image]

The first problem if there are no values or there is an error when I submit it brings me back to the default WP login is there a way to stop this?

is there a way to echo the lost password form and registration form to the same spot/page like how it's done on the wp_login_form?
and what's the best way to style these forms. since the PHP tag does it for me.

```
<?php wp_login_form( array('redirect' => home_url()) );?>
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( wp_lostpassword_url( get_home_url() ) ); ?>" alt="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Lost Password', 'textdomain' ); ?>">
<?php esc_html_e( 'Lost Password', 'textdomain' ); ?>
</a>
```

Comment: Add your code. ps You should not modify WordPress core files only work via themes and plugins

Comment: I added the code and I'm not talking about editing WP itself.